# Specifying custom type for an attribute of a UML class

Tags: attributes, arguments, uml, class-diagram

*i have a class with attribute called interval and i like to give this attribute a minimum and maximum value to bound this interval,*

***How can represent this?    Does this possible?***

Comment: Do you mean you want to put an minimum and maximum bound on the value, or that the value is a compound type containing both minimum and maximum?

Comment: Hi @PeteKirkham yes i meant value is a compound type containing both minimum and maximum

Answer (score 4):

Create a value type - a classifier with the *«data type»* stereotype - for the compound type, then use that as the type of the attribute.

For example, this says *ClassA* has a public attribute called *interval* of type *Interval*, and *Interval* is a value type which has public *min* and *max* attributes of type *double*:

```
                                +----------------+
+-----------------------+       |   «data type»  |
|        ClassA         |       |    Interval    |
+-----------------------+       +----------------+
| + interval : Interval |       | + min : double |
+-----------------------+       | + max : double |
                                +----------------+
```

As *Interval* is a value type, its identity is not important, so it would be held by value in *ClassA* and  would probably be implemented by a struct (if the target language supports values and structs; you can't have a value type in Java for example so the stereotype would be implemented by convention, as it is for String in Java so you have to remember not to use == on strings as their identities don't matter).

You can put a *«uses»* dependency from *ClassA* to *Interval*, but it is implicit from the attribute's type so it is common to omit it.

Answer (score 2):

I mostly agree with @Pete Kirkham I would use a Datatype instead of a Classifier with the <> stereotype but if I am right it is a partial response.
@Pete Kirkham truly responded to how model attribute with a min and a max bounds, I guess that @Chriss still want to know how to specify the value.
For this you have several ways (depending of your meaning), you can:

1. specify a default value for your attribute.
2. made an object diagram, instantiated your attributed and then specified the values.

Hoping it helps ...

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to put a limit to a value, another option is to specify an [OCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Constraint_Language) constraint over your attribute that limits its possible values.

context ClassA inv:
self.attributeA >= 1 and self.attributeA <= 10

Comment: thank you @Marco Brambilla.should i need to add this line of constraint using constraint model element?and then link the constraint to the specified property?

Comment: Yes, it's a constraint. You can link it to the class. Notice that this is a way of constraining a single value attribute (for instance, an integer). If you meant to say that your interval has two borders, and each of them has a max and min value (E.g., the min value must be included between 0 and 10, and the max value between 50 and 100), you should define a constraint for each.